# Sending data from .js file to .php using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send data from `.js` file to `.php` but it is not working.

I tried to search and find solution but anything didn't work for me. I guess there is issue in URL path but I am not sure.
I am using `win10`, `chrome`, `Netbeans` and `XAMPP`.

**ed.js :**

```
function delete_row(id) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "modify.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {delete_row: "deleted_row", row_id: id},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**modify.php :**

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$databasename = "exDB";

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, "exDB");
echo "<script>alert('alert');</script>";

 if (isset(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'delete_row'))) {
  $row_no = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'row_id');
    mysqli_query($con, "delete from exDB where id='$row_no");
    echo "success";
    exit();
 }
?>
```

I even put alert in `.php` file but I am not getting it.

Comment: Remove the round brackets from the `data`

Comment: Have you checked what the request is actually doing in the console? It should give you an error code at the very least

Comment: do you know how the ajax mechanism works?

Comment: what is in your console? there some 500 error or 400 error for ajax url?

Comment: @KinjalMistry I did but still not working.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Unfortunately there is nothing on output.

Comment: @madalinivascu I am new in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a simple typo

In your javascript you called this parameter `deleted_row` and in your PHP you test a variable called `delete_row`. So amend one so they match

```
if (isset(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'deleted_row'))) {
```

> When developing, specially if yo are developing on a LIVE Server where Error Reporting will of course be turned off, you should add these lines to sctipys that you are developing/testing

```
<?php 
   ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
   ini_set('log_errors',1); 
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

> And if you are using the MYSQLI_ API also

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

> Errors then become much easier to identify and see